# Multidemension array to single array by combianing values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array with following format.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
            (
                [keyword] => thumbnail_follow
                [content] => width
            )

    [1] => Array
            (
                [keyword] => thumbnail_resize
                [content] => yes
            )

)
```

My desire output is following

```
Array
(
    [thumbnail_follow] => width
    [thumbnail_resize] => yes
)
```

What I have tried so far?

1. `array_shift()` but this remove duplicate keys and output become

   ```
   Array
   (
       [keyword] => thumbnail_follow
       [content] => width
   )
   ```
2. `array_column` I am able to get only single type of values. For example `array_column($array, 'keyword')`

   ```
   Array
   (
       [0] => thumbnail_follow
       [1] => thumbnail_resize
   )
   ```

Using `array_column` and `loop`, I can get desire output but there must be some more efficient way to do it but I am known from this

Can you please help me guys?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) 's third parameter `index_key` you can do it. Please look at 2nd example of function.

Use it like this

```
print_r( array_column($array, 'content', 'keyword') );
```

You should get your desire output by this.

Comment: Thank you @Hassaan it works. I did not notice the third parameter

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$newArr = [];
foreach($yourArr as $row) {
   $newArr[$row['keyword']] = $row['content'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for the way to do it without using `loop`